# How to create a light chasing effect

Tags: lightprobe

I'm trying to create a light effect where I have a wall of lights that will "chase" 1 column after the other.

The thought process is to create an array, then get the ID of the array object I want to light up, add a certain amount of frames in which they are light, then fade out, then the next one, so on. I can do it the long way, by animating the value of the emission, but it would be nice to do it proceduraly.

thx.

[image: Light wall]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could unwrap with the *Project from View* option, and in the *UV Editor* scale down all the UVs with the *Individual Origins* option on. Give your object a material with a *Gradient Texture* plugged into a *ColorRamp*:

[image]

Now keyframe the location value of the *Mapping* node:

[image]

Comment: OMG!! this is amazing!!! exactly what I needed!!! this is a week part of my blender knowledge. Nodes.. Just don't know what to use when.. But this is great!!!